# QML item visiblity vs CPU performance

Tags: qml, pyside2

How I can turn off items (mainly texts, which shows sensors readings), so it will not consume CPU power? Visibility = false not work 100% correct for me.

I have a lot of sensors connected to the program. On the python side, they are really lightweight - they consume around 2% of CPU (windows task manager readings). But when I run GUI, the whole consume around 28%, and when I turn off visibility of texts, it drops down only for about few % - maybe to 22%.

Below I present small example, so you can check how it works on your machine. On this example, when it runs visible, it took about 5-6% of CPU power, when I turn off visibility, it slightly drops to 4-6% and when I minimize window, it drops to below 1%. Via turning off the items visiblity I would love to achieve the result as of minimizing the window, so the GUI would completely avoid rendering those texts and I can do other things.

It's worth adding that I would like to be able to turn off individual readings (via checkboxs), not the entire grid, so using the Loader probably won't work in my case. In texts I'm also using superscripts, subscripts, degree signs, etc. so sometimes it's RichText, sometimes not. I'm not sure if it is possible to make here some Repeater?

main.py:

```
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import random
import threading

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QIcon
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal, Property


class TestPythonBackend(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.random_float = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        thr1 = threading.Thread(target=self.func, daemon=True)
        thr1.start()

    def func(self):
        while True:
            self.random_float = [random.random() * 1, random.random() * 2, random.random() * 3, random.random() * 4, random.random() * 5, random.random() * 6, random.random() * 7, random.random() * 8, random.random() * 9, random.random() * 10, random.random() * 11, random.random() * 12]
            self.random_float_property_changed.emit()
            time.sleep(0.02)

    random_float_property_changed = Signal()

    @Property(list, notify=random_float_property_changed)
    def random_float_property(self):
        return self.random_float


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    test_python_backend = TestPythonBackend()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("test_python_backend", test_python_backend)
    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

Window {
    id: window
    width: 1280
    height: 800
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property var randomFloat: test_python_backend.random_float_property


    CheckBox {
        id: checkBox
        text: qsTr("Visibility")
        checked: true
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.left: grid1.right
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 200
        anchors.leftMargin: 200
        onCheckStateChanged: checked ? grid1.visible = true : grid1.visible = false
    }


    GridLayout{
        id: grid1
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        columns: 3
        anchors.leftMargin: 50
        anchors.bottomMargin: 50
        anchors.topMargin: 50
        width: parent.width/2

        Text {
            id: text1
            text: qsTr("Data 1: ") + randomFloat[0].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text2
            text: qsTr("Data 2: ") + randomFloat[1].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text3
            text: qsTr("Data 3: ") + randomFloat[2].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text4
            text: qsTr("Data 4: ") + randomFloat[3].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text5
            text: qsTr("Data 5: ") + randomFloat[4].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text6
            text: qsTr("Data 6: ") + randomFloat[5].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text7
            text: qsTr("Data 7: ") + randomFloat[6].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text8
            text: qsTr("Data 8: ") + randomFloat[7].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text9
            text: qsTr("Data 9: ") + randomFloat[8].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text10
            text: qsTr("Data 1: ") + randomFloat[0].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text11
            text: qsTr("Data 2: ") + randomFloat[1].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text12
            text: qsTr("Data 3: ") + randomFloat[2].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text13
            text: qsTr("Data 4: ") + randomFloat[3].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text14
            text: qsTr("Data 4: ") + randomFloat[3].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text15
            text: qsTr("Data 5: ") + randomFloat[4].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text16
            text: qsTr("Data 6: ") + randomFloat[5].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text17
            text: qsTr("Data 7: ") + randomFloat[6].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text18
            text: qsTr("Data 8: ") + randomFloat[7].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text19
            text: qsTr("Data 9: ") + randomFloat[8].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text20
            text: qsTr("Data 4: ") + randomFloat[3].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text21
            text: qsTr("Data 1: ") + randomFloat[0].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text22
            text: qsTr("Data 2: ") + randomFloat[1].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text23
            text: qsTr("Data 3: ") + randomFloat[2].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text24
            text: qsTr("Data 4: ") + randomFloat[3].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text25
            text: qsTr("Data 5: ") + randomFloat[4].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text26
            text: qsTr("Data 6: ") + randomFloat[5].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: text27
            text: qsTr("Data 7: ") + randomFloat[6].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext1
            text: qsTr("Data 1: ") + randomFloat[0].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext2
            text: qsTr("Data 2: ") + randomFloat[1].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext3
            text: qsTr("Data 3: ") + randomFloat[2].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext4
            text: qsTr("Data 4: ") + randomFloat[3].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext5
            text: qsTr("Data 5: ") + randomFloat[4].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext6
            text: qsTr("Data 6: ") + randomFloat[5].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext7
            text: qsTr("Data 7: ") + randomFloat[6].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext8
            text: qsTr("Data 8: ") + randomFloat[7].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext9
            text: qsTr("Data 9: ") + randomFloat[8].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext10
            text: qsTr("Data 1: ") + randomFloat[0].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext11
            text: qsTr("Data 2: ") + randomFloat[1].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext12
            text: qsTr("Data 3: ") + randomFloat[2].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext13
            text: qsTr("Data 4: ") + randomFloat[3].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext14
            text: qsTr("Data 4: ") + randomFloat[3].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext15
            text: qsTr("Data 5: ") + randomFloat[4].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext16
            text: qsTr("Data 6: ") + randomFloat[5].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext17
            text: qsTr("Data 7: ") + randomFloat[6].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext18
            text: qsTr("Data 8: ") + randomFloat[7].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext19
            text: qsTr("Data 9: ") + randomFloat[8].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext20
            text: qsTr("Data 4: ") + randomFloat[3].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext21
            text: qsTr("Data 1: ") + randomFloat[0].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext22
            text: qsTr("Data 2: ") + randomFloat[1].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext23
            text: qsTr("Data 3: ") + randomFloat[2].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext24
            text: qsTr("Data 4: ") + randomFloat[3].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext25
            text: qsTr("Data 5: ") + randomFloat[4].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext26
            text: qsTr("Data 6: ") + randomFloat[5].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Text {
            id: ttext27
            text: qsTr("Data 7: ") + randomFloat[6].toFixed(4)
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        Image {
            id: img1
            sourceSize.width: 100
            sourceSize.height: 100
            source: "Qt_logo_2016.svg"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            rotation: randomFloat[9]
        }

        Image {
            id: img2
            sourceSize.width: 100
            sourceSize.height: 100
            source: "Qt_logo_2016.svg"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            rotation: randomFloat[10]
        }

        Image {
            id: img3
            sourceSize.width: 100
            sourceSize.height: 100
            source: "Qt_logo_2016.svg"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            rotation: randomFloat[11]
        }
    }
}
```

Qt image:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)#/media/File:Qt_logo_2016.svg

My specs:

- Laptop with Ryzen 5 4600H, GTX 1650Ti, 16GB RAM and SSD drive
- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.4
- PySide2 5.15.2

Comment: It's likely all of the `text:` bindings on your Text objects are contributing. I would switch this over to watch randomFloat change via an onRandomFloatChanged: handler and then imperatively set each `text:` in plain Javascript (e.g. `text15.text = qsTrData5 + randomFloat[4].toFixed(4)`. This will eliminate a lot of binding activity. You should also precompute the qsTr calls so they aren't being performed every time randomFloat changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for comment. Could you post minimal working example of what are you suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach to eliminate a lot of binding activity:

```
[...]
    property var qsTrCache: []; 

    Component.onCompleted: { 
        qsTrCache["Data 1: "] = qsTr("Data 1: ");
        [...]
    }

    onRandomFloatChanged: {
        // You could also use two different Texts instead of precomputing qsTr() calls.
        text1.text = qsTrCache["Data 1: "] + randomFloat[0].toFixed(4);
        text2.text = qsTrCache["Data 2: "] + randomFloat[1].toFixed(4);
        // Etc.
    }
[...]
        Text {
            id: text1
            font.pixelSize: 12
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }
[...]
```

Thanks @JarMan for the comment re: precomputing.

Comment: By precomputing, do you just mean something like this: `property var qsTrCache: []; Component.onCompleted: { qsTrCache["Data 1: "] = qsTr("Data 1: ") ... }`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for me :/ Do you have maybe other suggestions?

Comment: Share more details with us. How is it not working?

Comment: Unfortunately, the CPU usage has not decreased

Comment: Have you attempted to profile the application? https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-performance-monitor.html What does that indicate is using the CPU?

Comment: Also, try removing this: `textFormat: Text.RichText`.

Comment: I've already removed RichTexts where it was possible. Thanks for the link! I will try to profile my app

Comment: What I've discovered is that "layer.enabled: true" helps to reduce CPU usage, when used on items, which are static.